# How to create column chart in Excel with strings on both axis

Tags: string, excel, charts

I want to do something so simple and realized Excel doesn't have straight way to do it, if it exists.

```
**Name Pet**
 Peter  dog
 Peter  cat
 Mary   cat
 Mary   dog
 John   cat
 Peter  dog
 Peter  dog
 Mary   dog
```

Just a simple column chart that given the name in X-axis I get two bars (dog,cat) for each name (Peter,Mary,John) with each bar the size of the count of the strings in Pet column.

I can count the number of Peter's pets (Dog=3, Cat=1) for example and then graph that with the number, but I'm doing a massive data chart and need Excel to automatically create the column chart for me.

Comment: Please edit your question, it not very clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot chart.

1. Go to "Insert" tab on the ribbon.
2. Click on "Pivot Table" and click "Ok" on the wizard which should create a new Worksheet
3. On the right, you should see a "PivotChart Fields" area. Hover your mouse over "Name" icon and drag drop it on the "Legend Series" box below.
4. Then hover over the "Pet" and drop it on the "values" box. It should be "Count of Pet". If it is "Sum of Pet", click on it and select "Value Field settings" and change it to count
5. Then move onto the actual pivot table itself by clicking anywhere on it. Go over to the "Analyze" tab on the ribbon and click on pivot chart. Choose your column chart and it should be there.

Comment: Thanks for that, this almost got me to what I want but still I see one bar for each name and I need two separate bars (cat and dog)

Comment: Ok try this. Drag the "Name" over to "Rows" then drag "Pet" over to Rows as well but underneath "Name". Keep the "Count of Pets" the same in Values.